# How to start 2 bash files (node.js and mongodb) when the pc starts but keep their terminal open?

Tags: server, startup

I have 2 bash files that initializes the server; one for the database and the other for the code.

I've put in the startup applications preferences to start both of them but their terminal is not visible, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the bash files directly in startup applications, you can have it call `gnome-terminal --command='<path_to_.sh>'` for each service.  That should do what you're looking for.

Comment: perfect, thanks! I still think ubuntu is tooooo complicated.. :S but thanks